# traer un registro a partir de fecha máxima SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

actualmente estoy tratando de optimizar un script, tengo el siguiente query

```
 DECLARE @ProcessDate DATETIME = '20220930'

SELECT 
Id, MAX(Fecha) Fecha , Balance

FROM Cuentas
WHERE Fecha <=@ProcessDate
AND Id IN ('60159','59973')

GROUP BY Id,Balance
```

el cual me muestra el siguiente resultado

```
Id           Fecha         Balance
5997321      2010-08-27     0
6015967      2012-07-12     0
6015967      2008-01-17     0.01
6015967      2007-11-09     1.8
6015967      2007-11-30     4.85
6015967      2007-12-31     4.87
5997321      2007-10-30     500
5997321      2007-10-31     500.13
5997321      2007-11-30     502
5997321      2007-12-31     503.95
5997321      2008-01-31     505.9
5997321      2008-02-29     507.73
5997321      2008-03-31     509.7
5997321      2008-04-30     511.61
5997321      2008-05-31     513.59
5997321      2008-06-30     515.52
5997321      2008-07-31     517.52
5997321      2008-08-31     519.52
5997321      2008-09-30     521.67
5997321      2008-10-31     523.91
5997321      2008-11-30     526.09
5997321      2008-12-31     528.36
5997321      2009-01-31     530.63
5997321      2009-02-28     532.7
5997321      2009-03-31     534.99
5997321      2009-04-30     537.22
5997321      2009-05-30     539.53
5997321      2009-06-30     541.78
5997321      2009-07-31     543.65
5997321      2009-08-31     545.52
5997321      2009-09-30     547.34
5997321      2009-10-31     549.22
5997321      2009-11-30     551.05
5997321      2009-12-31     552.83
5997321      2010-01-30     554.62
5997321      2010-04-29     872.73
5997321      2010-05-01     883.87
5997321      2010-06-01     886.91
5997321      2010-07-01     889.87
5997321      2010-08-01     892.93
6015967      2007-10-11     3032.55
6015967      2007-10-31     3046.8
5997321      2010-04-06     3572.73
5997321      2010-02-25     4584.62
5997321      2010-03-01     4587.58
5997321      2010-03-18     4587.91
5997321      2010-04-01     4602.73
6015967      2007-08-10     5000
6015967      2007-08-31     5013.75
6015967      2007-09-29     5032.55
```

me trae todo el historial por Id para los campos seleccionados aun y colocándole el Max a la fecha, lo que quiero es traer una sola fila por Id siempre con la fecha máxima y que sea menor o igual a la variable @ProcessDate, por ejemplo este es el resultado que espero

```
Id           Fecha         Balance
6015967      2012-07-12     0.00
5997321      2010-08-27     0.00
```

Como puedo realizar esto, ya que el max no me funciono, si alguien me ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de hacer lo que solicitas.

```
Create table Cuentas (id varchar(10), fecha date, balance float)

Insert into Cuentas (id, fecha, balance)
Values
('5997321','2010-08-27',0),
('6015967','2012-07-12',0),
('6015967','2008-01-17',0.01),
('6015967','2007-11-09',1.8),
('6015967','2007-11-30',4.85),
('6015967','2007-12-31',4.87),
('5997321','2007-10-30',500),
('5997321','2007-10-31',500.13),
('5997321','2007-11-30',502),
('5997321','2007-12-31',503.95),
('5997321','2008-01-31',505.9),
('5997321','2008-02-29',507.73),
('5997321','2008-03-31',509.7),
('5997321','2008-04-30',511.61),
('5997321','2008-05-31',513.59),
('5997321','2008-06-30',515.52),
('5997321','2008-07-31',517.52),
('5997321','2008-08-31',519.52),
('5997321','2008-09-30',521.67),
('5997321','2008-10-31',523.91),
('5997321','2008-11-30',526.09),
('5997321','2008-12-31',528.36),
('5997321','2009-01-31',530.63),
('5997321','2009-02-28',532.7),
('5997321','2009-03-31',534.99),
('5997321','2009-04-30',537.22),
('5997321','2009-05-30',539.53),
('5997321','2009-06-30',541.78),
('5997321','2009-07-31',543.65),
('5997321','2009-08-31',545.52),
('5997321','2009-09-30',547.34),
('5997321','2009-10-31',549.22),
('5997321','2009-11-30',551.05),
('5997321','2009-12-31',552.83),
('5997321','2010-01-30',554.62),
('5997321','2010-04-29',872.73),
('5997321','2010-05-01',883.87),
('5997321','2010-06-01',886.91),
('5997321','2010-07-01',889.87),
('5997321','2010-08-01',892.93),
('6015967','2007-10-11',3032.55),
('6015967','2007-10-31',3046.8),
('5997321','2010-04-06',3572.73),
('5997321','2010-02-25',4584.62),
('5997321','2010-03-01',4587.58),
('5997321','2010-03-18',4587.91),
('5997321','2010-04-01',4602.73),
('6015967','2007-08-10',5000),
('6015967','2007-08-31',5013.75),
('6015967','2007-09-29',5032.55);
```

**Operador Apply**

Igualando el conjunto exterior con el interior, el mismo devolverá una fila por cada una de las del exterior. Entonces, del exterior hay que devolver las filas por id, y el operador apply traerá los datos relativos a la máxima fecha.

```
DECLARE @ProcessDate DATETIME = '20220930'

SELECT distinct 
Cuentas.Id, ct.fecha , ct.balance

FROM Cuentas
cross apply (
    Select top (1) * From Cuentas c 
    where c.id = Cuentas.id 
     and c.fecha<=@ProcessDate
    order by fecha desc 
) ct
WHERE cuentas.Id IN ('6015967','5997321');ç
```

He cambiado el id in, porque en tú query no existen los ids que has puesto como ejemplo.

[image: Res1]

**Max**

```
DECLARE @ProcessDate DATETIME = '20220930'

SELECT 
Id, Fecha , Balance

FROM Cuentas
WHERE Fecha <=@ProcessDate
AND Id IN  ('6015967','5997321')
and fecha = (Select MAX(fecha) from Cuentas c where c.id = Cuentas.id 
);
```

El proceso es muy similar, pero hay alguna diferencia, como que si hay dos registros que encajan con una fecha. Tendrías dos filas y con con Apply solo una.

Por lo demás se monta de la misma manera. Un conjunto exterior relacionado con un conjunto interior.

[image: ResMax]

[Operador Apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

[Subquery correlativa y otras formas de conseguirlo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/subquery-correlativa-y-otras-formas-de-conseguirlo/)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar usar el compando ORDER BY, y si solo quieres un registro puedes usar el TOP, quedaria algo asi:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
Id, MAX(Fecha) Fecha , Balance

FROM Cuentas
WHERE Fecha <=@ProcessDate
AND Id IN ('60159','59973')    
GROUP BY Id,Balance
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
```

espero funcione.